# how to find the breakpoint counts of date string

Tags: python, python-3.x

CASE 1:
Here is my dataframe ，it has almost 4 million rows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMwDC.png)
Each row of the 'date' column has a different start date ， a different end date and number of days， dates separated by commas.
I want to add two columns， one is a string fragment with date greater than 2023/4/18, the other column is the number of date breakpoints whose date is greater than 2023/4/18， for example：'2023-1-01,2023-2-10,2023-4-18,2023-5-16,20-5-17,2023-6-19' is the row in the 'dates' column ,the result I want to get is '2023-4-18,2023-5-16,20-5-17,2023-6-19' and its breakpoint is 2.
CASE 2:
The same table as the picture above in mysql ， how to extract the rows containing dates greater than 2023/4/18.

I try to do these with for but it's too tedious .please help me , thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved by applying different functions to `date` column.

Here I create a mock dataframe based on your example:

```
from datetime import datetime, date
import pandas as pd

# mock dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date": ["2023-01-01,2023-03-30", "2023-01-01,2023-02-10,2023-04-18,2023-05-16,2023-05-17,2023-06-19", "2023-01-01,2023-02-10,2023-04-18,2023-04-19,2023-05-16,2023-05-17,2023-06-19,2023-12-19"]
})
```

Here I create two functions:

1. `filter_dates` to leave only dates greater than `"2023-04-18"`.
2. `count_date_breaks` - to count number of times when difference between two neighbour dates isn't equal to 1 day.

```
date_format = "%Y-%m-%d"

def filter_dates(dates, start_date="2023-04-18"):
    dates_parsed = map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, date_format), dates.split(","))
    dates_filtered = filter(lambda x: x >= datetime.strptime(start_date, date_format), dates_parsed)
    return ",".join(map(lambda x: datetime.strftime(x, date_format), dates_filtered))

def count_date_breaks(dates):
    date_breaks = 0
    if len(dates.split(",")) == 1:
        return date_breaks
    
    dates_parsed = list(map(
        lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, date_format),
        dates.split(",")
    ))
    
    for date, prev_date in zip(dates_parsed[1:], dates_parsed[:-1]):
        if (date - prev_date).days != 1:
            date_breaks += 1
    return date_breaks
```

Function applications and the final result:

```
df["date_filtered"] = df["date"].apply(filter_dates)
df["date_breaks"] = df["date_filtered"].apply(count_date_breaks)
df
```

Output:

```
                                                date  \
0                              2023-01-01,2023-03-30   
1  2023-01-01,2023-02-10,2023-04-18,2023-05-16,20...   
2  2023-01-01,2023-02-10,2023-04-18,2023-04-19,20...   

                                       date_filtered  date_breaks  
0                                                               0  
1        2023-04-18,2023-05-16,2023-05-17,2023-06-19            2  
2  2023-04-18,2023-04-19,2023-05-16,2023-05-17,20...            3
```